# How to deal with a quotation-mark at the end of a string literal?

Tags: python

I have a script that generates a very simple python script. Basically it replaces `@test@` in

```
IMPORTANT_TEXT='''@text@'''
```

with a string that can contain `'` and `"` symbols. If it ends with `'` the python script is broken. How can I avoid this happening? I do not want the saved text to be altered contentwise. So no additional spaces etc.

Comment: Can you show an actual example of broken code?

Comment: use `\"` (or `\'`) to escape the quotation mark?

Comment: Maybe: `'''\n@text@\n'''[1:-1]`?

Comment: I think I prefer Rick Teachey's answer, as `repr(value)` makes it hard to continue working with this string without python automatically escaping the characters again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
template = 'IMPORTANT_TEXT=@text@'
value = '''He said "No I don't".'''
script = template.replace('@text@', repr(value))
print(script)  # IMPORTANT_TEXT='He said "No I don\'t".'
```

Comment: `repr` does exactly what I want. Thanks.